# throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i can't find the solution.please help..
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').load()
}

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
const authorRouter = require('./routes/authors')
const bookRouter = require('./routes/books')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout')
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: false }))

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose'))

app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/authors', authorRouter)
app.use('/books', bookRouter)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

Comment: `process.env.DATABASE_URL` is returning `undefined`, check your environment variables if `DATABASE_URL` is present and have correct value.

Comment: your environment variables have not loaded

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file? And what is your `NODE_ENV` environment variable currently set to?

Comment: i solved this. it's ```.env``` file problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create the .env file on your root project. Then under that file copy-paste this line i.e

```
DATABASE_URL="192.168.1.1:3000"
```

then on main server file may be app.js or server.js or somethingelse.js file before the line i.e `const mongoose = require('mongoose')` copy-paste this line

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

and then console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL)`// This will return your Database URL`

Hope you understand the concept.